# I keep getting this error "pygame.error: display Surface quit" and dont know what to do

Tags: python, pygame

Im a beginner in python just to learn it and have been watching tutorials, specifically Tech w Tim. I was following a tutorial and got the error "pygame.error: display Surface quit". I tried to follow some tips from other similar questions but I couldn't get them to work.

Here is the code.

```py
import pygame

width = 500
height = 500
win = pygame.display.set_mode((width, height))
pygame.display.set_caption("Client")

clientNumber = 0

class Player():
    def __init__(self, x, y, width, height, color):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.width = width
        self.height = height
        self.color = color
        self.rect = (x, y, width, height)
        self.vel = 3

    def draw(self, win):
        pygame.draw.rect(win, self.color, self.rect)

    def move(self):
        keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()

        if keys[pygame.K_LEFT]:
            self.x -= self.vel

        if keys[pygame.K_RIGHT]:
            self.x += self.vel

        if keys[pygame.K_UP]:
            self.y -= self.vel

        if keys[pygame.K_DOWN]:
            self.y += self.vel

        self.rect = (self.x, self.y, self.width, self.height)

def redrawWindow(win, player):
    win.fill((255,255,255))
    player.draw(win)
    pygame.display.update()

def main():
    run = True
    p = Player(50, 50, 100, 100, (0, 255, 0))
    clock = pygame.time.Clock()

    while run:
        clock.tick(60)
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                run = False
                pygame.quit()

        p.move
        redrawWindow(win, p)

main()
```

This is what I get in the terminal too

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:/Users/Owen/Documents/Oof/Client.py", line 60, in <module>
    main()
  File "c:/Users/Owen/Documents/Oof/Client.py", line 58, in main    
    redrawWindow(win, p)
  File "c:/Users/Owen/Documents/Oof/Client.py", line 41, in redrawWindow
    win.fill((255,255,255))
pygame.error: display Surface quit
```

Answer (score 0):

When [`pygame.quit()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/pygame.html#pygame.quit) is executed, all PyGame modules will be uninstalled. Every further call to a PyGame function throws an exception.
You call `pygame.quit ()` in the middle of the loop, but because the loop executes once to the end, you will get an exception on the following PyGame API calls.
Do not call `pygame.quit()` in the event loop, but call it once after the application loop:

```py
def main():
    # [...]
    
    while run:
        clock.tick(60)
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                run = False
                # pygame.quit() <----- delete

        p.move
        redrawWindow(win, p)

    pygame.quit() # <----- insert
```